# Tikz overlay picture over the frame title in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I am trying to put a tikz overlay picture - A nice, thick red 'X' over a word - On the frame title of a Beamer frame.  However, the overlay tikz picture in the frame does not recognize the nodes given in the title.

For example, I try:

```
\newcommand{\crd}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture, baseline=.5ex]\coordinate (#1);}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Some \crd{p}Crossthis\crd{q} Title}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[red, thick] (p) -- (q);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

And I get:

```
ERROR: Package pgf Error: No shape named q is known.
```

How can I put an overlay on the title?

Comment: Do you also get "No shape named p is known"?  If not, it would be very strange that one coordinate was there but the other wasn't.

Comment: @Andrew: When I run the OP's MWE I do get a warning about p first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beamer evaluates a frame's contents in a nonstandard way.  The frame's body is evaluated before the frame's title.

Here is an adaptation of your MWE that puts the effect in the title and demonstrates the order of evaluation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{n}

\newcommand{\crd}[1]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture, baseline=.5ex]\coordinate (#1);}
\begin{frame}{%
    \stepcounter{n}($n=\then$)% 
    Some \crd{p}Crossthis\crd{q} Title%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
            \draw[red, thick] (p) -- (q);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\stepcounter{n}($n=\then$)% 
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

You have to run this twice to get the underline effect.

Comment: Presumably, Mr Tables wants "CrossThis" crossed out, in which case `baseline=-.5ex` would be better.  (Yes, I know this was wrong in the original question ...)

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, I presume the same.  Maybe I can tweak it later.